# JavaFX. Добавление элемента интерфейса при нажатии кнопки

Tags: java, javafx

Прошу подсказать как можно добавлять новые элементы например в HBox по нажатию кнопки. Имеется такая кнопка:

```
btn1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        label.setText("Ok");
        hbox1.getChildren().addAll(label);
        hbox1.requestLayout();
    }
});
```

Но после нажатия, только редактируется содержание `label`, добавления же ещё одного элемента `label` не происходит. Пробовал `hbox1.clear()`, но тогда он стирает всё содержимое бокса и добавляет только один `label`.

Answer (score 1):

Вы изменяете и добавляете уже существующий объект. Скорее всего уже добавленный. Измените первую строку в методе `handle` на `Label label = new Label("Ok");`.